# Icons do not appear when I use react-native-vector-icons

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am trying to use react-native-vector-icons in my project(react-native in android), however every icon I try to use stays with(?) Instead of the icon, I followed the installation correctly, I don't know what is going on.

How I am trying to use the icon (there is no compilation error):

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

Answer (score 0):

After adding the module (yarn add), try to execute `react-native link` on the command line before building the app.

read more here: 
https://www.reactnative.guide/12-svg-icons-using-react-native-vector-icons/12.0-intro.html